# Is There A Way To Add Weight Or Order To Tags?

Tags: tags, order

I'm wondering if it's possible to add a 'weight' value to tags... similar to how one can specify an 'Order' for pages to indicate their placement on menus.

Eg. I may have dozens of keywords but I will -always- want 4 or 5 to appear at the top of a 'tag cloud', regardless of their popularity or slug or ID.

I guess I could add a new table to the db and relate that to the term_taxonomy table, but I was hoping there was already a solution.

Comment: Have you read this article: [WordPress Taxonomies Extra Fields the easy way](http://en.bainternet.info/2012/wordpress-taxonomies-extra-fields-the-easy-way)

Comment: Interesting. I see variations on this all the time. I dunno how efficient it will be... IOW: I think adding a related table would execute a lot faster, but definitely worth a look. Thanks!

Comment: Check out [Term Menu Order](https://wordpress.org/plugins/term-menu-order/)

Comment: Cool. Thanks. This guy modifies the terms table... I rarely think that's a great idea, but hey it works.